# How to implement PetaPoco with existing C# 3-tier win app

Tags: windows, orm, c#-4.0, petapoco

can anyone help me with converting my project to use PetaPoco?

here is my issue. backend is SQL 2010 database .NET fraimework 4.0

I have an existing 3-tier win app in C# that uses a custom DAL -- each Data call uses stored procs with parameters and either returns dataset or specific value as needed -- each call accepts dataset referenced parameter and baseClass parameter (base class is identical to DB table schema well mostly)

I want to replace my custom DAL with PetaPoco but keep the 3-tier layout

the app is relying on predefined base classes as DTO to pass info between UI-BAL-DAL

does anyone have a sample/example of app solution layout as to how to use PetaPoco in 3-tier enviroment code example would be very helpfull

thanks in advance...
 Vlad

Answer (score 0):

### Example not really needed

All you have to do is get acquainted with PetaPoco library. The best way is its documentation. It's not a complicated/complex library, so you should get up to speed with it quite quickly.

If you also have you application broken down into projects for each layer (UI, BL, DAL), then the easiest thing to do is to create a new DAL project and implement all used functionality of existing DAL but use PetaPoco in this one. Then just change your project references and voila. That's it. You can keep your POCOs/DAO. If you've used IoC then it will be even easier because instantiating DAL repositories (or whatever you're using) is probably done via some DI container.

#### Layering and PetaPoco

PetaPoco has nothing to do with application layering. If you use it in 3-tier applicatin that's fine.

#### What are you using now?

You didn't mention which DAL library (if any) you're using right now. If you don't, then using PetaPoco will result in less lines of code and much simplified object mapping.

Comment: oops..  too fast on the ENTER :-).   I am sorry if my question was not very clear, but I am not asking about how to actually use PetaPoco it self, but rather how to implement it in my project properly. right now I have an application 3t (UI/BLL/DAL) My DAL is a hand coded DAL with lots of baseObjects and stored proc calls.  ALL DataTransfers are done via base DTO between the layers. and frankly I am not sure how to replace this with PP DAL. hence the example request.  I need something to look at to get an idea.

Comment: @Vlad: As said. If you have your data fetching contained in your DAL layer then just rewrite it to use PetaPoco instead of custom Connection/Command/DataReader/DataAdapter/DataSet. If you've read your data using DataReader you've converted it to yur DTOs. Instead of that just use the mapping capability of PetaPoco as in `db.Query<Article>("SELECT * FROM Article")`. If that's not a problem, then try to ask you question in a way so we can understand your problem. Start using it and you'll see it's simple. Don't create your connections, commands and readers and similar.

Comment: @Vlad: I think [this page](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) shows enough code to get you started. If you have problem s with integrating it into your application then create a pilot project that uses PetaPoco. Maybe it will be easier for you to understand how to convert your DAL code.